# Best way to present a quick access option in a login form

Tags: forms, login

I'm building a web app that will require users to do some small data entry.

By default, when a user logs in, they are taken to their dashboard to see the status of their account. From here they can use the navigation bar to go to the data entry page.

On the login form, how can I display a "quick access" option that will allow the user to go straight to the data entry page, rather than the dashboard? Situations where I see this being ideal is an employee needing to quickly log in and enter their data on a tablet.

Here's an example of such an option:

[image: Data entry login]

Would there be better ways to show this option?

Comment: How frequently would a user want to do this? Is it an occasional thing? or is it likely that they would always want to go straight to the data entry page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. An option (select) for the user to choose where they'd like to be
   redirected to. It should also remember their previous choice.
2. Make
   the data-entry page accessible without login but as soon as the user
   submits they are prompted to provide their credentials? This could
   be beneficial in scenarios where data entry takes precedence (e.g.
   get all the forms filled out before you forget, worry about the
   login later)

Comment: These are definitely good suggestions. If you're able to allow users to fill the data-entry page before they have to login, it's great !

Comment: I quite like the second option. This app will be used in supermarkets and food stores, so it means a random employee can do the data entry, and then give the laptop/tablet to their manager, where they can then log in. Saves having to give out lots of passwords, or giving out the managers password.

Answer (score 0):

Actually they'll have to type their login informations, click on the checkbox and then click on the button. In the other case they would have to type their login informations, click the button and then click the desired tab.

In both cases they would have to click twice so I'm not sure if it makes it faster.

I'd suggest to take them directly to the data entry page or to remember the last visited one. So they get back to it when they log in.

Otherwise, it's a matter of seconds to click on a tab. I'm not sure if the checkbox would increase the overall user experience. And I guess they'll have the option to stay logged between sessions, right ?

However, if you think it's really important, I'd probably take a look at the home page more than the login step.

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of data is very small, say one or two fields, maybe that itself could be on the "dashboard" screen or there would be a side tab that the user could slide out instantly, like a drawer, that allows them to enter the data right over the top of the dashboard.  Again, since I don't know exactly what they are inputting, I'm taking a guess but could you put the open input fields for what they wanted to enter right on the dashboard and then a list of the latest actions or latest "inputs" underneath that (think activity stream, if that's what you are showing on the dashboard)?  Kind of like the idea in FB where you have an open status field and then the other stuff already listed out underneath from your previous posts?